# creating polynomial in python by reading coefficient from a file

Tags: python, polynomials

I'm new to python. I'm creating polynomial by reading polynomial coefficients from text file. When I run below code, I'm getting error as

> "TypeError: cannot accumulate on a scalar"

```
read_file = open('coefficient.txt','r')
coefficient = read_file.read()
p1 = poly1d([coefficient])
print(p1)
```

Please give your inputs

Comment: what's your content of `coefficient.txt`?

Comment: Binary value. For example I'm giving data like 1,1,0,1,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert `string` list to `int` list before you pass it to poly1d:

```
from numpy import poly1d
read_file = open('coefficient.txt','r') # 1,1,0,1,0 store in file coefficient.txt
coefficient = read_file.readline().split(',') # coefficient =['1', '1', '0', '1', '0']
p1 = poly1d(map(int, coefficient)) #convert it to [1, 1, 0, 1, 0] with map for python2
#p1 = poly1d(list(map(int, coefficient))) #for python3
print(p1)
```

Output:

```
   4     3
1 x + 1 x + 1 x
```